# plugging an lm() into a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, lm

New coder, long time lurker first time poster, so this question is probably going to be really nooby and bad....

For a proof of concept i'm attempting to run an lm() in a for loop in R, and then perform an anova() on that lm(). The variables of interest in my dataset are yield, practice and treatment. I have 2 levels in my practice, "PL" and "LT", and would like to run an lm(yield~practice*treatment) twice; once for all observations when practice = "PL" and and once for when practice = "LT", then anova() both of those lm()'s.

I've never done loops in R before, so far I have:

```
for (i in 1:2) {lm(Yield~Practice[i]*Treatment)}
```

How do I adjust this so that it calls just the first level of Practice (which is PL) in the first iteration of the loop and then the second level(LT) in the second iteration? Then I'd like to write the anova() into the loop as well.

I know itd be easier just to subset() by Practice and then run 2 anova()'s, since theres only 2 levels in practice, but, I'm just practicing and would like to see how this is done for future application. Thanks!

Comment: SO has a [bunch of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+regression+loop) on running regressions in a loop in R. Do any of them help?

Comment: Have a look at lmList() in package nlme. But also, if you create a sample dataframe and paste the output of dput(your.df) it will be easier to help.

Comment: If you want to have `Practice` as an independent variable in the regression, then you need to have both levels of practice in the subset that you feed to `lm`. If you feed `lm` a factor that has only a single category, that's no different from excluding the factor from the regression.

Comment: I'm thinking the same as eipi10 - if you're looking at the interaction between Practice and Treatment, but in each regression Practice doesn't vary (e.g. it's just PL), the model won't tell us anything?

Answer (score 1):

Step1: create a unique set including values from `practice`

```
#assume all you variables are in `data`
lvl_Practice<- unique(data$Practice)
```

Step2: loop

```
for ( i in 1:length(lvl_Practice) ){
    #create a subset data 
    data_sub <- subset(data,Practice== lvl_Practice[i])

    #create the linear model. If it is the first loop,
    #then the model name will be lm1
    assign(paste("lm",i),lm(Yield~Practice*Treatment,data=data_sub))
}
```

This method will give you `lm1` and `lm2` if there are only 2 levels in the `practice`.

## Edit 06/12/2015

According to the comment from @eipi10 below, the answer can be revised as:

```
for ( i in unique(data$Practice) ){
    #create a subset data 
    data_sub <- subset(data,Practice== i)

    #Note1: create the linear model. If it is the first loop,
    #then the model name will be lm1.
    #Note2: There is no need to put `Practice` factor in the model  
    assign(paste("lm",i),lm(Yield~Treatment,data=data_sub))
}
```

## Edit 09/12/2015

According to the comment from mine below, the answer can be revised as:

```
for ( i in unique(data$Practice) ){
    #create a subset data 
    data_sub <- subset(data,Practice== i)

    #Note1: create the linear model. If it is the first loop,
    #then the model name will be lmPL and lmLT.
    #Note2: There is no need to put `Practice` factor in the model  
    assign(paste("lm",i,sep=""),lm(Yield~Treatment,data=data_sub))
}
```

Comment: Cleaner to use `for (i in unique(data$Practice))` and then `subset(data, Practice==i)` or `data[data$Practice==i,]`. However, a separate problem for this regression model is that it will produce an error, because after subsetting, `Practice` will have only one level.

Comment: For example, with the built-in `iris` data frame: `lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species*Sepal.Width, data=iris[iris$Species=="setosa",])`. `Error in contrasts <- *tmp*, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels`.

Comment: @eipi10, good points! I've just purely solved the problem from programming side, but ignored the statistical meaning behind. A `lm` on subset data is equivalent to `lm(Yield~Treatment,data=data_sub)`.

Comment: Thanks everyone! This really helps.

Comment: @Sixiang.Hu , i used your suggestion and when I try to run an anova() on lm1 it says that "object 'lm1' not found", even though it should have been created in the loop. Any idea why it didnt work? Do I need to make an lm[i] object before it gets assigned the lm() in assign()?

Comment: @AndyPetran, if you look at your environment variables, you will find `lm PL` and `lm LT` as oppose to `lm1` and `lm2`.  This is because: 1: `paste` should have parameter `sep=""` and 2: the `i` have value of `PL` and `LT` as oppose to `1` and `2`. I will change the code above.

Comment: @Sixiang.Hu, Alright I can run the code now, and run an `anova()` on `lmLT` and `lmPL`, respectively, thanks! Out of curiosity, would there be a way to incorporate the `anova()` of each lm (lmLT and lmPL) into the for loop, so that when I run it the `anova()` output for each one spits right out?